# Bowling Counting algorithm from InterviewStreet

Tags: algorithm

I don't know if this is the right section... but here goes:

Last weeks contest on interviewstreet (Code Sprint 3) had a problem called bowling. (10 pin bowling, N frames). The point is to count the number of ways to score M points by playing N frames.

Problem Statement is here: http://pastebin.com/cyeLML8U

I'm pretty sure I've solved the problem using 2 dimensional DP. However, I get the 3rd sample data wrong (1 Frame, 25 points). The sample answer is 1, however I get 6.

This is their explanation of the sample answer:

```
For the third case, there is only 1 way. Score a strike in the first frame, score another strike with the first extra ball, and an additional 5 with the second extra ball.
```

However, can't you score a strike in the first (and only) frame, then score any of the following in the subsequent extra frames?

```
10 5
9 6
8 7
7 8
6 9
5 10
```

I can't wrap my head around why "1" is the right answer.... I've looked on wikipedia for the rules too.

Their answer is probably right, and I'm probably overlooking something REALLY obvious. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot get 9 pins with the first extra ball and then 6 pins with the second extra ball because there is only 1 pin left standing when you bowl the second extra ball.

Comment: Unless I've missed something, the rules linked in the original question don't actually make it clear that the pins aren't reset for every ball bowled.  Working by the rules as linked, there's nothing wrong with the posted question's assumptions, but if we assume they actually meant to cover the actual scoring rules of bowling, you're correct.

Comment: @AdeStringer - Absolutely correct, it's not so much of a logic error as it is an error in the completeness of the question. But it's the only way to make the "correct" answer hold up.

Comment: I knew I was overlooking something obvious... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

But if you don't get a strike on the second ball, you only have the opportunity to "pick up the spare." That is, you only get 10 pins. So if you get a strike on the first ball and then 9 pins on the second ball, the most you can get on the third ball is 1.

Answer (score 1):

The way I read it, your answer is technically correct, but I don't think the question was asked correctly.

Within the constraints as set out in the link in your question, I can't see what's wrong with your solution.  In real life, the pins won't actually be reset unless you've knocked them all down or have bowled twice (or both), so - as others have said - the only way you can score 25 from a 1 ball frame in real life is strike, strike, 5.

Basically, the question didn't give you the correct constraints.  I don't think it's valid to say you got the answer wrong, because the question was poorly phrased.

Comment: Yeah I haven't bowled since high school... This never occured to me. Thanks!